# How to pass multiple checkboxes to the Action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, freemarker

I am using Struts 2 and Freemarker. This is my action class:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WelcomeAction {
    
    private String userName;
    private String gender;
    private List<String> fruits;
    private String fruit;


    public String execute() {
//      if(!userName.equals("a"))
//      {
//          return "fail";
//      }
//      else {
//          return "SUCCESS";           
//      }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }   
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFruitsPicked() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public void setFruitsPicked(String fruitsPicked) {
        this.fruit = fruitsPicked;
    }

    public List<String> getFruits() {
        return fruits;
    }

    public void setFruits(List<String> fruits) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }
    
    public WelcomeAction(){
        fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
        fruits.add("apples");
        fruits.add("oranges");
        fruits.add("pears");
        fruits.add("peaches");
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my `.ftl`:

```xml
<input type="checkbox" list="fruits" name="friut[]" value="apples" /> Apples<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" list="fruits" name="friut[]" value="oranges" /> Oranges<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" list="fruits" name="friut[]" value="pears" /> Pears<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" list="fruits" name="friut[]" value="peaches" /> Peaches<br />
```

This is how I tried printing:

```xml
<#list fruits as item>${item}</#list>
```

But above command prints all the items in my list that I added in my constructor. Of course, I only want the items that were checked when the form was submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name="friut[]"` should be `name="fruits"`. The JavaBean property name is `fruits`, not `fruit` (nor `friut`... note the typo). I don't know about that `[]` is meaningful for Struts, better said, for OGNL/`ValueStack.setValue` that the `ParametersIntercaptor` uses. (It understands `fruits[0]` though, which is useful to set an element in an existing list.). So at the end Struts has ignored the parameters, so you end up with the original list. Where does `list="fruits"` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```jsp
<s:checkboxlist name="fruit" list="fruits"/>
```

You don't need to preserve  multiple checkbox'es values in the multiple `<input>` fields, so there's not necessary many `<input>` fields. Struts2 should render it appropriately. Multiple values will come to the action with *comma separated values*.

In your code you have to add getters and setters for the `list` the same way as for `fruit` that contains selected values. The [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) will do its job populating your action called with the setter when the form is submitted.