# How to send javascript array to struts action by using jQuery Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, type-conversion

I am new to Struts 2. I want to send a javascript array to a Struts action class by using jQuery AJAX request. 

The alert is working fine, the `execute()` is not working.

When I put  `System.out.println("language : "+ language);` in the `execute()` method, the output is

> language : `null`.

```js
var langArr = [];
    $("#language").each(function()
    {
      var selectedLang = $("select").val();
      var selectedValues = $(this).val();
      langArr.push(selectedValues);
     });
    alert("Languages : " + langArr);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "getProjectPost",
        data: { "language" : langArr },
        dataType : "json",
        traditional: true,
        success:
            function()
            {
             alert("Success");
            },
        error: 
           function()
            {
             alert("Error");
            }
    });
```

This is my action class

```
public class ProjectPostAction {

    private int[] language;

    public final int[] getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public final void setLanguage(int[] language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {          
           System.out.println("language : "+ language[0]);
           return "success";    
    }
```

Comment: What is printed in the alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery serializes data sent as parameters using [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) internally when doing ajax request with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The data should be set as array of integers or string with comma separated list of integers, so jQuery can correctly serialize it before sending with the request.

You can send an array parameter to struts2 only with `traditional` setting because struts using type conversion to populate a property of the action using keys as parameter names.

**So, the array should be an array of primitive integers but your array contains other objects that are not primitive integers.**

To demonstrate you can see this [<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/um17umdL/) to understand how to get parameter values and serialize it the same way like is doing `$.ajax`.

Struts2 also can convert a string containing a comma separated values by default type conversion. For example you can see [how checkbox list values are passed to struts action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416470/573032).

Answer (score 0):

To use JSON with Struts2, your best option is to import the [Struts2 JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html).

Then,

1. you'll get automatic JSON conversion when exposing data *from* the action *to* the JSP, by using the **Json Result** [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265), BUT
2. you'll need to include the **Json Interceptor** in your interceptor stack to have the JSON conversion *from* the JSP *to* the action, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363922/1654265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721059/1654265).